# How to write a one-page file to the disk in one flush?

Tags: c, linux, file, io, kernel

Say I have 4096 bytes of data that I want to save in a file on Linux using C. It should take exactly one page and can be flushed only once. However, if I do it using multiple calls to the kernel i.e. write piece by piece, the kernel might interrupt my sequence to flush the current content to the disk and then when I finish writing it would flush agian. So to make sure it doesn't waste its flushes I would have to make only one call to the kernel. That would be `write`. Does calling `write` once guarantee that the flush will only happen once?

`man` pages offer some `MAP_UNINITIALIZED` that I could use together with `MAP_FIXED` to map some prewritten page to the file and then `msync` to write it to the file, but they say it's only available on embedded devices.

I tried looking into kernel source code, but it's very hard. There are many nested calls and the deepest I went is `vfs_write`. From there it calls some function pointers and starts to branch into multiple calls.

Comment: `mmap` et. al. _is_ available on all linux machines. But, no, generally you can _not_ control when the kernel decides to flush a page from the page cache to disk. You can only "hint" at it. But, why worry? The kernel is very smart about this. We really need to see your _existing_ code to be able to comment further. Please _edit_ your _question_ and post your code in a code block here. Otherwise, [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/785231)

Comment: @CraigEstey Unfortunately, I can't do that. I am planning a server application and the whole design is defined to be as efficient as possible. The very answer to this question might completely change my design. My server should maintain a general database. I can only say that my current plan assumes that files stored on the disk are files with length that is a whole number of pages, internal structure is complex. I will want to change only some segments of files and I want to update only those pages containing them. In the next comment...

Comment: @CraigEstey ... The total size of files may be huge. So in cases of system crash I don't want to have too much of lost changes. For that I need to controllably limit the number of dirty pages. On the other hand, I can't always flush every change because that would damage the disk on long runs. Luckily, there is not so many different files in database and I can predict how often and how much some files will change. Because of that I could make a very efficient flusher. But hinting all that to the kernel sounds like too much communication between my server and the kernel...

Comment: @CraigEstey So having the control over flushes sounds really useful. I just don't understand how Linux, the system that is supposed to be the one and only option for servers can have such flaws? I understand that it gives a lot of administration advantages, but for programming servers, kernel is just too cocky...

Comment: Write a test program that exercises your flush. This would be an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Add benchmarks and measure various methods. If you can't measure it, you can't tune it. Why not look at postgres, mysql, sqlite3, nosql existing databases and look at how they do flush/sync under linux? Your understanding of linux [kernel] is somewhat limited. Are you aware of the journaling in (e.g.) `ext4`? You should be able to write an abstract API that can serve as the basis.

Comment: What about disk drives that have their own ram cache? Or systems that use flash disks as cache for the hard drives? There is more to the problem than you think. What about crash recovery? Whether you use `O_DIRECT`, `mmap`, `madvise`, `msync`, `write`, `fsync`, `fdatasync`, `O_SYNC` or combinations, write the API so the actual impl is hidden in the API. What API would you use for record fetch, modify, write back and use transaction rollback? The test program should be able to inject faults/crashes, test recovery and measure performance for all possible scenarios (i.e. unit test/system test)

Comment: Did you look at `io_uring`?

Comment: @CraigEstey That looks attractive, thank you! However, that is an in-kernel API... I would prefer something more portable. That's why I ask if `write` will surely be only one flush

Comment: Want portable? Just use postgres or mysql. Many man hours have already gone into making them robust/fast. Why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: @CraigEstey Because I don't want to depend on anyone's code. The tools you mention are huge and are so much likely to contain bugs and what I need is so tiny and could contain no bugs. After all, they also had to implement it using the same repertoir of functions that I have. So they would have to know the answers to the same questions I ask. What if I were a mysql dev?

Comment: @CraigEstey omg, wait, I missed to read your whole 3 comments, somehow I only read the last one, wait, sorry

Comment: @CraigEstey Okay so, here's then my situation: Yes, I want to write an API that my server would use. And what I told you about "whole number of pages files" is kind of a description of what's in the plan. Secondly, I can't assume too much about underlying hardware, otherwise, yes, I know I could probably implement some raw IO drivers or sth like that. I want to use already existing file systems and just inform the kernel of dirty page when I want. This is because my server is supposed to be a distributed process over the whole network of clients. Something like tor where you have clients and..

Comment: @CraigEstey ...and tor relays. Every client would serve the network a little bit and I can't make assumptions about their hardware or filesystems. All I can do is prevent unecessary writes that happen between me and the kernel. How kernel prevents the writes between itself and drivers is not in my hands...   I know that some filesystems can be mounted so that the changes are flushed as late as possible. That is again not in my hands.

Comment: @CraigEstey Should I maybe implement a whole new filesystem? Would then I have the control over flushes, i.e. could then I use the direct IO? And then simply advise the clients to use my filesystem? yeah, about writing a MRE, uhm I feel sorry for my disk. I did some tests on tmpfs and it looks like write is "atomic" but that might be true only for tmpfs and not on ext4...

Comment: @HalidBeslic: If you are concerned about data loss in case of power failure or similar, then you may want to read [this page from the PostgreSQL manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/wal-reliability.html), to read about how that software deals with the problem. This is a very complex problem.